# Deserialization error when trying to use JSON with HBASE's REST gateway

Tags: json, hbase

I'm trying to use the hbase rest API. I've read the docs here (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate), but they seem to be incomplete (doesn't cover json) and [out of date](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201402.mbox/%3CCAOEq2C5i4OH9%2BwtiwPAoX_pAp7it%2BoLAPNTBvQZWamQ05_4dcQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E).

I've also run across [this gist](https://gist.github.com/karmi/1218928), which is mostly what I'm going off of.

Here is the (insert) request I'm trying to send:

- URI: `http://server:8070/table/row1/data`
- Headers:

  - `Content-Type` : `application/json`
  - `Accept` : `application/json`
- HTTP verb - `POST`

and the json payload (where key, column, and $ are all base64 encoded values):

```
{
    "Row": {

        "key": "NjQ=",
        "Cell": [{
            "column": "NjQ=",
            "$": "NjQ="
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error 500 Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser$Input@3da0b822; line: 2, column: 5]
 (through reference chain: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.model.CellSetModel["Row"])
```

The error seems to suggest that there is something that should be an array and isn't. I've tried putting square brackets just about everywhere, and I can't get it to do anything other than change the nature of the error message slightly.

I had a look through the [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=hbase.git;a=tree;f=hbase-rest/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/model;hb=HEAD) and that seems to suggest that the placement for the square brackets that I have is correct. However, as far as I can tell the entire request looks to be correct. I'm not very fluent in Java though, so maybe I'm missing something.

What is the proper JSON syntax for inserting a record with the hbase rest gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now the correct format:

```
{
    "Row": [{

        "key": "NjQ=",
        "Cell": [{
            "column": "NjQ=",
            "$": "NjQ="
        }]
    }]
}
```

Where:

- key - is the row key
- column - is the column name
- $ - is the data that you are storing in the given table, column, and row.